# Java: fatal error, access violation in Java_sun_awt_shell_Win32ShellFolder2_compareIDsByColumn

Tags: java, access-violation, jfilechooser

The program pops up a JFileChooser, and if the user goes into details view then clicks on the column headings, the program dies completely with an exception access violation and the problematic frame as named in the title above.

Googling the name of the problematic frame indicates this was a known bug in 2012, which was apparently (?) claimed to have been solved, but we've got it happening in JRE 7.0_17-b02.

Suggestions, workarounds (other than "don't click on the column headings"), etc., most welcome.

thanks

Comment: Java 7 update 21? Worth a try at least. ;) How up to date is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is these bugs:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7177373

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7199708

They appear to have been fixed in the unreleased Java 8 about a year ago, but were recently backported to the just-released Java 7 update 40.

I think upgrading to 7u40 will fix your problem.